# Update in multiples rows

Tags: sql-server

How can I write an `UPDATE` when I have a sub query?

Take a look:

```
UPDATE People 
SET Name = dbo.formatt_name((SELECT Name 
                             FROM People 
                             WHERE idInstitute = 12)) 
WHERE idInstitute = 12
```

I've created a function `formatt_name(str)` that returns a formatted string.

I would like to update all names on my table using that function, someone knows how can I get this ?

I get this error message:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1.

I know, just one result for set the update. But, I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Here no need of subquery. You are using same where condition in subquery.

Comment: I've to change all names, so the subquery is returning all names needing to change.

Comment: You have to update all  rows means you just add query without condition. 
 UPDATE People
SET Name = dbo.formatt_name(Name)

Comment: I want to update only the names of people that belongs to institute = 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, you have to update all records of the table where peoples belongs to  institute =12 and add another condition Name is not null also .

```
UPDATE People SET Name = dbo.formatt_name(Name)  where  
idInstitute=12 and Name IS NOT NULL
```

**Edited:**

From my understanding you have to format all names in each record.

```
 idinstitute  Name 

  12       Antony | Jhon | Cris | Peter

  12       kEvin| JhOn | antony | PCrIS
```

here you no need of subquery.   find the sample function for the  formatted string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[formatt_name] (@InputString VARCHAR(max) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Index INT
DECLARE @Char CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString VARCHAR(255)
SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 2
SET @OutputString =
STUFF(@OutputString, 1, 1,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString,1,1)))
WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
SET @Char = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
IF @Char IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&','''','(')
IF @Index + 1 <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
IF @Char != ''''
OR
UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index + 1, 1)) != 'S'
SET @OutputString =
STUFF(@OutputString, @Index + 1, 1,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index + 1, 1)))
END
SET @Index = @Index + 1
END
RETURN ISNULL(@OutputString,'')
END
```

and query for update,

```
 UPDATE People SET Name = dbo.formatt_name(Name)  where  
    idInstitute=12 and Name IS NOT NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Pnomani, the name must to be a subquery to get all the names. I don't want to turn all the names de same. thank you for reply... but doesn't work

Comment: what is your expectation result ? can you give some example

Comment: ok, some table have 4 names : antony  | JhOn | CrIS | PETER 
The result must to be :                   Antony | Jhon  | Cris | Peter

Comment: @Summerson , i have edited the post. please find which satisfies your expectation.

Comment: thank you man, this worked , I should pass the table name as a parameter. Thank you so much.  The problem now is the function get all date from table, but this i can fix . Thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use subquery? You should be able to update rows like this:

```
UPDATE People
SET Name = dbo.formatt_name(Name) 
WHERE idInstitute = 12
```

Comment: Dmitry all datas are in the database, i need a query to change all of them

Comment: This query will update names of ALL people which have `idInstitute = 12` with value computed by `dbo.formatt_name` function. Isn't this what you're trying to do actually? You should try it, check the result and tell us what's wrong, if it is.

Comment: Does't work because the parameter 'name'  must to be a value returned by another query. this subquery returns some values, so i got that error on Sql Server. I'm trying. Do you have another idea ? Thanks for helping

Comment: Then you need to make sure than another query returns ONLY ONE row and you will be ok. Like, add a more specific `WHERE` clause to the query inside `()`. Can you write such a query? Because `idInstitute = 12` is obviously not the kind of condition that will be true for only one row.

Comment: ok. I've a database and all clients names is there. I've to make a script that correct all names. My function works , but only one result. When I'm using tha expression doesn't works. There's some possibility to do that without a line to line, manually...?

Comment: @Sumerson I must ask again - have you tried running this query on your data?`UPDATE` IS the kind of operator, that updates values in all rows which correspond to specified `WHERE` condition. So, simply put, for each of found rows it will execute `SET Name = dbo.formatt_name(Name) ` statement. Function parameter `Name` will be different for each of the rows.

Comment: Yap, correct, my mind was tired yesterday. I couldn't see. heheheh thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Return one row

```
UPDATE PEOPLE p
SET p.Name = dbo.formatt_name(p.Name)
WHERE p.id = p.id and p.idInstitute = 12
```

Comment: Instead of a new answer, you can update the same content in your existing answer.

Comment: Nfyfr , as I sai bellow, i need to get this result : some table have 4 names : antony | JhOn | CrIS | PETER The result must to be : 
Antony | Jhon | Cris | Peter